# Aspectj exceptions handling on multiple matching advices

Tags: java, exception, aspectj, aspect, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have 2 aspects that are applied on the same method. 
When the method executes correctly I have no problem, everything is working fine and both aspects work as expected. 
The problem is when the method throw an exception. In these cases, the first aspect re-throw correctly the exception, but the second aspect is generating a nullpointerexception. 
I was able to reproduce the problem isolating the case on a unit test in a separated project.
Those are the aspects (actually I removed all the logic, at the moment they do nothing):

```
@Aspect
public class LogContextConstantAspect {

    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(logContextConstant)")
    public Object aroundMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, LogContextConstant logContextConstant) throws Throwable {
        try {
            Object res = joinPoint.proceed();
            return res;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
@Aspect
public class LogExecutionTimeAspect {

    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(logExecutionTime)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, LogExecutionTime logExecutionTime) throws Throwable {
        try {
            Object res = joinPoint.proceed();
            return res;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

while those are the 2 custom annotation that I implemented

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LogExecutionTime {

    String paramKey() default "execution_time";
}
```

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Documented
public @interface LogContextConstant {

    String name();

    String value();
}
```

then I created a simple class with the following methods

```
public class AspectSimple {

    public int execute() {
        System.out.println("ok");
        return 1;
    }

    public int failSimple() throws CustomException {
        throw new CustomException("ko");
    }

    @LogExecutionTime
    public int failWithAspect1() throws CustomException {
        throw new CustomException("ko");
    }   

    @LogContextConstant(name="test", value = "test")
    public int failWithAspect2() throws CustomException {
        throw new CustomException("ko");
    }   


    @LogExecutionTime
    @LogContextConstant(name="test", value = "test")
    public int executeWithAspect() {
        return 1;
    }

    @LogExecutionTime
    @LogContextConstant(name="test", value = "test")
    public int failWithAspect3() throws CustomException {
        throw new CustomException("ko");
    }   
}
```

and finally this unit test

```
public class TestSample {

    static AspectSimple as = null;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setup() {
        as = new AspectSimple();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        int res = as.execute();
        assertEquals(1, res);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        int res = as.executeWithAspect();
        assertEquals(1, res);
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        try {
            int res = as.failSimple();
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            assertNotNull(e); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail();
        }
    }   

    @Test
    public void test4() {
        try {
            int res = as.failWithAspect1();
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            assertNotNull(e); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail();
        }
    }       

    @Test
    public void test5() {
        try {
            int res = as.failWithAspect2();
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            assertNotNull(e); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail();
        }
    }       

    @Test
    public void test6() {
        try {
            int res = as.failWithAspect3();
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            assertNotNull(e); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail();
        }
    }       

}
```

All tests are running correctly, only the last one (test6) fails.

the application is running on java 8, with aspectj 1.9.4 and junit 5.
Here the complete pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.pivimarco.samples.aspects</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspect-sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        org.baeldung.executable.ExecutableMavenJar
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                                <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <properties>
                                <excludeTags>slow</excludeTags>
                            </properties>
                            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                            <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                        <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <properties>
                        <excludeTags>slow</excludeTags>
                    </properties>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <parameters>true</parameters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.4</version>
                        <scope>compile</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <proc>none</proc>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If I apply just a single aspect the CustomException is throwed as aspected,
but when both aspects are applied I'm getting a nullpointerexception.

I've also tried to declare the precedence of the aspects, using DeclarePrecedence annotation, but it didn't work

```
@DeclarePrecedence("it.pivimarco.samples.aspects.LogContextConstantAspect,it.pivimarco.samples.aspects.LogExecutionTimeAspect")
```

This is the stacktrace of the NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at it.pivimarco.samples.aspects.AspectSimple.failWithAspect3_aroundBody10(AspectSimple.java:35)
    at it.pivimarco.samples.aspects.AspectSimple$AjcClosure11.run(AspectSimple.java:1)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:170)
    at it.pivimarco.samples.aspects.LogContextConstantAspect.aroundMethod(LogContextConstantAspect.java:18)
    at it.pivimarco.samples.aspects.AspectSimple.failWithAspect3(AspectSimple.java:35)
    at it.pivimarco.samples.aspects.TestSample.test6(TestSample.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: I tried with JUnit 4 and 5 in Eclipse but cannot reproduce your problem. I have not tried with Maven, though. Your aspect and test code are both a bit more complicated than necessary but there is no test failure.

Comment: Actually your Maven POM does not run any tests at all, so I fixed it locally. Now I can reproduce the problem with AspectJ 1.9.4, but with 1.9.2 it works as expected. Can you confirm that, please? Then I will write an answer and also create an AspectJ bug ticket.

Comment: Hi @kriegaex, you're right, I runned all test via eclipse,not with maven, so probably there is an error on pom.xml configuration. Changing aspectj version to 1.9.2 solved the issue for me as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you uncovered a bug in the AspectJ compiler (versions 1.9.3, 1.9.4) which does not occur in version 1.9.2, as I said in my comment. I have just created [AspectJ bug ticket #552687](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=552687) on your behalf. Please check there for further updates. For now you can just downgrade to 1.9.2 and continue working.

---

**Update:** AspectJ 1.9.5 with the bugfix is out. Please try again. My retest was successful.